# TT abbreviation/acronym meaning in German language

Tags: abbreviation

I would like to know what **TT** abbreviation/acronym stands for and what it means. It is related to meeting rooms/business area. I could not find an answer on google search, related to this domain. A synonym for meeting room is "Tagungsraum", but can't figure out the double T.

Comment: That's no generally used or understood abbreviation and may be particular to the social / company context you encountered it in. 

As such it could even be a "denglish" term to sound 'cool' like "training and talk" or whatever.

Comment: Or, even "cooler": "Talk UND Training". So gehört im ICE: "...und nach dem Morning-Meeting, da haben wir die Local Markets gepollt und dann die Data in unsere Spreadsheets eingegeben...". At this point habe ich the World nicht mehr understandet.

Comment: Indeed, TT could refer to anything from "Tagungstermin" to "Tischtennis", depending on the context. TT is not a common abbreviation when it comes to meetings. Maybe with an example of usage we might be able to help

Comment: Thank you all for your replies. Indeed "Talk and Training" seems to be the answer, since some other rooms are defined by the activities that happen there.

Comment: How formal was the context in which you saw it? Are you sure it isn't just a crying emoji?

Comment: Der genaue Kontext könnte zu besseren Antworten führen, vielleicht auch in dem geklärt wird, ob es überhaupt ein dt. Terminus ist, oder, wie häufig spekuliert, ein englischer.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

"TT" is no generally used or understood abbreviation and may be particular to the social / company context you encountered it in.

As such it could even be a "denglish" term to sound 'cool' like "training and talk", "Talk UND Training" (thx bakunin) or [whatever could](https://abkuerzungen.woxikon.de/abkuerzung/tt.php) [be abbreviated](https://www.abbreviationfinder.org/de/acronyms/tt.html#aim) [as TT](https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/TT) with some phantasy.

Answer (score 2):

I never heard that abbreviation before.

According to [acronym finder](https://www.acronymfinder.com/TT.html) *TT* could simply mean *Talk To*, which would make the question out of topic for German SE, since no German is involved.

Comment: I'm not exactly impressed that an English acronym list does not contain German ones...